# Deploy resource adapter and application in websphere liberty image

Tags: docker, websphere-liberty

I have a requirement to create a spring boot application and connect it to EIS via dtpraUnisys JCA adapter. the flow is

Application -> ADapter RAR -> EIS

I want to use the websphere liberty image and then bundle the rar and the application jar file

Where should I give the rar file location, application jar file details.

is there any example which I can refer based on docker image

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of anything official, but I did go through something similar (but with Java EE instead of Spring Boot) with IBM MQ [on my Github](https://github.com/realModusOperandi/jms/tree/tekton/docker).

The basic idea is that you typically place resource adapters and other shared in /opt/ol/wlp/usr/shared/resources/ for Open Liberty or /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/shared/resources for WebSphere Liberty. I do that in my Dockerfile:

```
RUN mkdir /opt/ol/wlp/usr/shared/resources/wmq/ && chown -R 1001:0 /opt/ol/wlp/usr/shared/resources/wmq/
COPY --chown=1001:0 docker/wmq.jmsra.rar /opt/ol/wlp/usr/shared/resources/wmq/
```

Then you reference them in server.xml, using the `shared.resource.dir` variable:

```
<resourceAdapter id="mqJmsRa" location="${shared.resource.dir}/wmq/wmq.jmsra.rar">
   <classloader apiTypeVisibility="spec, ibm-api, api, third-party"/>
</resourceAdapter>
```

From there, you might have to create some config items. I'm not sure what EIS needs, but the entire server.xml syntax is documented [on the Open Liberty website](https://openliberty.io/docs/ref/config/) (this applies to WebSphere Liberty, too) so you can find what you need. You'll usually need to reference your resource adapter to set properties on it using the `properties.<adaptorName>` element.

This works for any type of application on Liberty. Deploying the spring boot app might require some extra steps. There's a good guide to deploy a spring boot app on Liberty in Docker [on the Open Liberty guides site](https://openliberty.io/guides/spring-boot.html).